# Rails way to generate select fild options

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I'd like to generate a select form field, where a user can select one entry of another model. Currently I do it this way:

`<%= f.select :wg, Warengruppe.all %>`
and in my Warengruppe model I defined the to_s method this way:

```
  def to_s
    return self.titel
  end
```

So I get an array of strings. But now I want to store just the id of the Warengruppe entry, so I need an array of `[[id,title],[id,title]....]`. Well I can write a method, that generates the array, but isn't there a more rails way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking for is;

```
f.select(:wg, Warengruppe.all.collect {|w| [ w.titel, w.id ] })
```